# opencv import causes python to crash

Tags: python, opencv

I've installed opencv using following command:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

And I'm using anaconda environment to run my code on Jupyter notebook. But When I try to import opencv like following:

```
import cv2
```

It gives a dialog with `Python has stopped working`. I've also tried to install opencv via conda like following:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

But this gives error:

```
following spec. found conflict
-opencv
-python 3.5*
```

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured out the solution. Just ran the following command and now it's working.

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```